# How to set a text Box Input type="text" in asp.net?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

How can I set input type to text only inside this text box?

I tried:

```
type="text";

remove toString() from cs
```

But they didn't work correctly.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtShort"  Width="200px"  value="abc"   runat="server" ValidationGroup="abc" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
```

.CS

```
'" + txtShort.Text.ToString().Trim() +
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I set input type to text only inside this text box."

Comment: You want to have only alphabets inside textbox?

Comment: I think you wants to allow only text in the text box

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict input of numbers in your textbox, you can also use client-side code - 
    `<asp:TextBox onkeydown="return !(event.keyCode>=48 && event.keyCode<=57);"></asp:TextBox>`

You can include keycodes for numpad0 to 9 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only need alphabets inside textbox you can use a regular expression like :-

```
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="only characters allowed" ControlToValidate="txtShort" ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z]*$" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use allow only alphabets using javascript method calling in the textbox with onkeypress event. you can try below code

```
   <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function allowAlphabets(evt) {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
            if ((charCode <= 90 && charCode >= 65) || (charCode <= 122 && charCode >= 97 || charCode==8)) {

                return true;
            }
            alert("Enter only Alphabets");
            return false;
        }
</script>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" onkeypress="return allowAlphabets(event)"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thank's a lot  sir